# Swift: "fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class..."

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

This is a simple class I wanted to have instantiated with two arrays to populate an NSTableView on a mac app:

```
class TableController: NSObject, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    var paintingNames:[String]
    var paintingKeys:[String]

    init(names:[String], keys:[String]) {
        paintingNames = names
        paintingKeys = keys
    //      breakpoint here shows both arrays have values
   }
...
}
```

When I step through the code as it is being initialized, everything works up to this point. Then I get this error:

```
"fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class..."
```

So I can can avoid this error, by adding the arrays optionals (not what I want as they are the tableView's dataSource) and adding an override init() call:

```
class TableController: NSObject, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

var paintingNames:[String]?
var paintingKeys:[String]?

override init() { // this gets called after the first custom init function

    // a breakpoint here shows the arrays are now both nil
}

init(names:[String], keys:[String]) { //this gets called first
    paintingNames = names
    paintingKeys = keys
    //      breakpoint here shows both arrays have values
}
...
}
```

Without the nil check on the arrays in the override init() call, the arrays are nil. Even with this bit of logic added:

```
override init() { // this gets called after the first custom init function
    if paintingNames != nil {
        paintingNames = [String]()
    }

    if paintingKeys != nil {
        paintingKeys = [String]()
    }
}
```

they are still nil.

What is going on here?

Comment: what is the point of the nil check? read it again, does it make any  sense?

Comment: I was grasping at straws with the nil check, that's for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why making the arrays as optionals works is because optionals are automatically assigned `nil`.

```
var paintingNames:[String]?
var paintingKeys:[String]?
```

does the exact same thing as

```
var paintingNames:[String]? = nil
var paintingKeys:[String]? = nil
```

You can actually remove the `init()` declaration at this point as your default initialiser is already implicitly created for you.

You haven't added any code to show WHERE the default initialiser is being called, I hope you aren't calling two `init()` functions... that is a recipe for unexpected results.

If you only ever want objects of this class to be instantiated using the `init(names:[String], keys:[String])` initialiser, just make your default initialiser throw an exception, i.e.,

```
init() {
    fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
}
```

This would prevent you from ever making the mistake of creating an object using `init()`. Another way would be to just make your `init()` into:

```
override convenience init() {
    self.init(names:nil, keys:nil)
}
```

In case you don't know, `convenience` initialisers allow you to call other local initialisers from within an initialiser.

Comment: "You haven't added any code to show WHERE the default initialiser is being called, I hope you aren't calling two init() functions... that is a recipe for unexpected results."   This was my problem. IB is calling init() as TableController is the delegate/data source for an NSTableView. This is my first mac app and NSTableView has a few more manual setup steps than UITableView!